# Android adapt realm to 64 bit

Tags: android, realm, 64-bit

I am migrating one application to 64 bit to make an update in Google Play store but, after follow android developers instructions, Google play console keeps saying I have to adapt to 64 bit.

Inside Analyze APK I have the following:
[image]

I have also included in my gradle file the following:

```
myApplication {
            minSdkVersion 21
            applicationId 'com.app.myApplication'
            targetSdkVersion 28
            versionCode 150
            versionName '2.8.0'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.myApplication
            manifestPlaceholders = [ROTATION_PREF: "unspecified"]
            ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'
        }
```

What I am missing?

Thank you,

Comment: You are missing the x86_64 library

Comment: How I can get it?

Comment: Where ever you got the others. Probably the Realm downloads page? Realm should distribute all the necessary platform versions.

Comment: I didn't get them from realm downloads page, I just delete the previous one's and make a rebuild to make appear them.

Comment: You mean they are being built from the native c++ source code? The configuration might be in some sore of Makefile then. But I don't know enough about that. You should expand your question with the entire folder structure and if you can find this Makefile, it's content.

Answer (score 0):

All problem was with realm version.
The one that I had was to old to adapt to 64-bit environment.

Once's I changed the version for a newer one, x86_64 library appeared.